# Use Inkscape To Align SVG to Top-Left Of Canvas

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg, alignment

I have an SVG which has bbox of something like

`SVGRect {x: 236.92999267578125, y: 99.98999786376953, width: 121.48001098632812, height: 224.70001220703125}`

How can I use Inkscape to position the graphic to the top left of the canvas so that the `x` & `y` values above are zero.

Edit: I have figured out using the align & distribute panel. However, inkscape is applying `transformation` & not actually changing the path co-ordinates, which is what I actually want.
[image]

--- EDIT ---
As per @Scribblemacher's request, here is a sample.

I want this:

```
<g transform=(-10, -10)>
  <path d="M329.66,99.99l22.1,4c0,0-14.5,52.9-2.1,51.6c0,0-11.7,72.7-10,83.7
        c0,0,18.8,81.1,17.3,85.4...>
```

to be converted into this:

```
<g>
  <path d="M319.66,88.99l22.1,4c0,0-14.5,52.9-2.1,51.6c0,0-11.7,72.7-10,83.7
            c0,0,18.8,81.1,17.3,85.4...>"
```

In other words, the transformation should be mapped onto the individual paths of the group, the actual co-ordinates of the path. The above 'M329.66,88.99' becomes 'M319.66,99.99'. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but can't you just open the SVG in a text editor and change the X and Y?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the problem, there are several ways to do this:

- Enable the "Snap to page border" snapping option, then just drag the object towards the corner
- With the object selected, you can manually set the X and Y coordinates from the toolbar
- With the object selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to open the XML editor and change the X and Y manually

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I tried the first two, however, they append `transform` attribute on the `<g>` group. What I want is for Inkscape to update the co-ordinate values for each path based on the new position of Top Left.

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample SVG (either the image or the code) that exhibits this problem? I can't replicate it in Inkscape 0.91. When I do any movement actions with the object, it's applying it to the `x` and `y` of the `<g>`, not adding a transform attribute.

Comment: Yes, thats what it is doing on my system as well. Perhaps, I wasn't clear enough. I want the transform to be applied on the individual `<Path>` element. Im updating the question with a sample, thanks.